# Как добавить что угодно на русском языке в Django

Tags: python, django

Есть класс в модели

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, verbose_name='e-mail')
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Пытаюсь добавить пользователя на русском, выдает ошибку

```
OperationalError at /admin/books/author/add/
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xD0\\x9A\\xD0\\xBB\\xD0\\xB8...' for column 'first_name' at row 1")
```

Подскажите как подправить

Comment: [похоже на проблему с mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2108824/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно создать БД с кодировкой utf-8. Как именно -- смотрите документацию по своей СУБД. Для PostgreSQL: `createdb -E utf-8` 
Исходники тоже в юникоде держать + в начале файлов прописывать `# encoding: utf-8`.